# Printing Multiple Data in Groups Python Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm very tempted to do this in SQL, but want to try this in Pandas:

I'm calling multiple variables within one data set and would like to join them alongside one another. Example:

```
print(len(data)) #Number of rows
print(len(data.columns))

print(len(data.index))

print("COUNTY COUNT")
c1 = data["County"].value_counts(sort=False)
print (c1)
```

.........and so on...

```
print("STATE COUNT")
c2 = data["State"].value_counts(sort=False)
print (c2)
```

.........and so on...

I'd like to achieve the following, but am having trouble using

```
c1.DataFrame(["County"], sort=False).sum()
```

.........
I've seen another chain using pd.dataframe...

Any suggestions/references as to how to efficiently and correctly organize these data as such?:

Thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `df.apply(lambda series: series.value_counts()).unstack().dropna()`. This will compute value counts for all columns simultaneously, returning a matrix with columns as in your current data and row indices containing all possible values in your data.

Unstack makes it flat, and dropna removes `nan`s (In your case, values that do not occur in a given column).

Comment: Thanks Yakym: I'm still experiencing an error. I'm confident I'm incorrectly calling my data. "unorderable types: int() > str(), sort order is undefined for incomparable objects"

Comment: Hi Tiffany. I am not sure if I can reproduce this error as I am not using Python 3. However, I cannot imagine comparisons occurring anywhere but in the `value_counts` call. Perhaps try `lambda series: series.map(str).value_counts()`. This will reset types for your output but should suffice for printing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I think it best to organize the original data set to include numeric values (duh)
This would avoid any errors I had been experiencing with other lines of code.

Once I organize accordingly, I believe forming a data frame should be simple. In other words, I'll have both nominal/ordinal values, both of which are originally represented in text-only.

Then, going to try pd.to_numeric
Concerned about empty cells being changed to numeric 0 values. Maybe I call NumPy?